# Import classes Phaser 3

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I have a problem cause I don’t know how it works.

I’ve created a scene where you can choose an upgrade for your character.
I have 3 upgrades you can choose from.

So I’m creating a class for each upgrade, I wanted to import them into the upgradeScene (UI).
I’ve tried this… but I can’t see anything with no errors in the console.

increase_speed.js

```
let rectC;
let cardC; //container

let increase_speed_title;
let increase_speed_description;
let increase_speed_btn;


export default class IncreaseSpeed extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor() {
        super('increase_speed');
    }

    preload() {
        this.load.image('cardbg', './Assets/UI/cardbg.png');
    }

    create() {

        const screenCenterX = this.cameras.main.worldView.x + this.cameras.main.width / 2;
        const screenCenterY = this.cameras.main.worldView.y + this.cameras.main.height / 2;

        rectC = this.add.image(0, 0, 'cardbg');

        increase_speed_title = this.add.text(-65, -100, 'Increase\nSpeed', {
            fontFamily: 'dogicaPixel',
            fontSize: '20px',
            align: 'center'
        });

        increase_speed_description = this.add.text(-80, 0, 'Lorem ipsum\ndolor sit amet', {
            fontFamily: 'dogicaPixel',
            fontSize: '15px',
            align: 'center'
        });

        increase_speed_btn = this.add.text(-65, 120, 'UPGRADE', {
            fontFamily: 'dogicaPixel',
            fontSize: '20px',
            align: 'center'
        });

        cardC = this.add.container(screenCenterX, screenCenterY, [rectC, increase_speed_title, increase_speed_description, increase_speed_btn]);
    }
}
```

upgradeScene.js in the create() function:

```
const increase_speed = new IncreaseSpeed(this, 300, 400);
this.add.existing(increase_speed);
```

I’m not sure if this is correct `export default class IncreaseSpeed extends Phaser.Scene` cause maybe should be a game object. But I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are adding a `scene` *(want it should stay a `scene`, and not use a different gameobject)*, you can simply call the function `this.scene.add(...)`:

```
this.scene.add(this, IncreaseSpeed, true);
```

instead of calling:

```
const increase_speed = new IncreaseSpeed(this, 300, 400);
this.add.existing(increase_speed);
```

and the Scene should be displayed, as an overlay.

> Here is a [link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Scenes.ScenePlugin.html#add__anchor) of this function.